# Solving elementary row operations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So I am faced with the following:
$$
\begin{align}
x_1 + 4x_2 - 2x_3 +8x_4 &=12\\
x_2 - 7x_3 +2x_4 &=-4\\
5x_3 -x_4 &=7\\
x_3 +3x_4 &=-5
\end{align}$$

How should I approach this problem? In other words, what is the next elementary row operation that I should attempt in order to solve it? I know how to do with 3 equations by using the augmented method but this got me a little confused.

Comment: Are you familiar with the method of Gaussian elimination?

Answer (score 3):

Write it as an augmented system:

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
      1&   4&   -2&  8 & 12\\
      0&   1&  -7&  2 & -4\\
      0&  0& 5& -1 & 7\\
      0&  0& 1& 3 & -5
    \end{array}\right]$$

Gaussian Elimination (Row-Reduced-Echelon-Form - RREF) will yield:

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
      1&   0&   0&  0 & 2\\
      0&   1&  0&  0 & 7\\
      0&  0& 1 & 0 & 1\\
      0&  0& 0& 1 & -2
    \end{array}\right]$$

Thus:

- $x_4 = -2$
- $x_3 = 1$
- $x_2 = 7$
- $x_1 = 2$

Comment: Putting matrices into the Latex area has been difficult for me, but it has been easy for you like drinking a glass of water. :D

Comment: @BabakS.: I created a little text file cheat sheet that I use for common LaTex items that I reuse because I am still too slow at typing things up and some of you are very fast! Feels like a time trial at times. Hope all is well with you my friend! Have a great day!

Comment: I wish I could have that valuable cheat sheet. Wanna sell it? How many $?? :D

Comment: Cheat sheet to the rescue! +1

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Use Elimination/ Substitution  or Cross Multiplication to solve for $x_3,x_4$ from the last two [simultaneous](http://www.mathcaptain.com/algebra/simultaneous-equations.html) equation.

Putting the values of $x_3,x_4$ in the second equation, you will get $x_2$

Putting the values of $x_2,x_3,x_4$ in the first equation you will get $x_1$

Answer (score 0):

By the Gauss-Jordan algorithm, your next step would be to make the $4x_{2}$ into a $0$, by the Type 3 elementary row operation: multiply row 2 by -4 and add that to row 1.